# Find $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+2x+5} \, dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

I imagine I should use the residue theorem here, but I'm not sure how to begin.

The book states that the answer to this problem is $\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}$

Comment: You aren't sure how to begin?  For starters, have you even attempted any particular contours?

Comment: the indefinite integral is given by $$\frac{1}{2} i \left(\sqrt{1-2 i} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-2
   i}}\right)-\sqrt{1+2 i} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1+2 i}}\right)\right)$$

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner : I wouldn't post a comment like that without saying something about which value of $\sqrt{1-2i}$ or $\sqrt{1+2i}$ should be there or about whether it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's the general layout of what I would do:

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{\frac12\operatorname{Log}(z)}}{z^2+2z+5}\\\begin{align}\int_0^{+\infty}f(x)~\mathrm dx&=\Re\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)~\mathrm dx\right]\\&=\Re\left[\oint_Cf(z)~\mathrm dz\right]\\&=\Re[2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f,-1+2i)]\end{align}$$

Where $\Re(x+iy)=x$ and $C$ is some common contour for integrals that go from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

It is unnecessary to use residue theory. Let $y=\sqrt{x}$, then the integral is transformed into an integral of a rational function $\int_0^\infty \frac{2y^2}{y^4+2y^2+5} \,dy$, which is handled by considering partial fraction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Using the keyhole contour
$$
\gamma=[i\epsilon,R+i\epsilon]\cup Re^{i\left[\sin^{-1}(\epsilon/R),2\pi-\sin^{-1}(\epsilon/R)\right]}\cup[R-i\epsilon,-i\epsilon]\cup\epsilon e^{i[3\pi/2,\pi/2]}
$$
as $R\to\infty$ and $\epsilon\to0$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2+2x+5}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_\gamma\frac{z^{1/2}}{z^2+2z+5}\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
\frac1{z^2+2z+5}=\frac1{4i}\left(\frac1{z+1-2i}-\frac1{z+1+2i}\right)
$$
and using the branch of $\sqrt{z}$ that is continuous on the inside of $\gamma$, where it is $\sqrt{x}$ just above the positive real axis and $-\sqrt{x}$ just below, we get
$$
\sqrt{-1\pm2i}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt5}2}+i\,\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt5}2}
$$